# Is it fine to create a folder name serializers or views when you have many views/serializers in Django?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am creating an app which has approx 40 views and serializers. Now my serializers.py and views.py are too big around 700 lines and 2300 lines respectively. I am thinking if I can create a folder and put all views files inside a separate file in the views folder and same with serializer then will it create any issue for the project in future?

Comment: I usally add views, serilizers, services, models, tests directory to all my applications.